# base class implementation in C#

Tags: c#, solid-principles

I am trying to implement a model so that the base class has like 5 properties and derived class will be implementing what it needs. as an example:

```
public class BaseClass
{
 public int a{get;set;}
 public int b{get;set;}
 public int c{get;set;}
 public int d{get;set;}
 public int e{get;set;}
}
```

and on the derived classes i want to have something like this:

```
public class DerivedClass: BaseClass
{
public override int a{get;set;}
public int derivedClass1 {get;set;}
}

public class DerivedClass1 :BaseClass
{
public override int a{get;set;}
public override int b{get;set;}
public int derivedClass1 {get;set;}
}

public class DerivedClass2 :BaseClass
{
public override int a{get;set;}
public override int b{get;set;}
public override int c{get;set;}    
public int derivedClass2 {get;set;}
}

public class DerivedClass3:BaseClass
{
public override int a{get;set;}
public override int b{get;set;}
public override int c{get;set;}
public override int c{get;set;}
public int derivedClass3 {get;set;}
}
```

by doing so I need to implement all base class objects. Is there a way of partially implementing the derived class like this

Thanks

Comment: It is unclear to me what you mean. I think you misunderstood what abstract classes are for - can you try to reword your question so it is more clear?

Comment: Yes, what problem are you having?  What have you tried and what happened when you tried it?

Comment: Your base class already provides all implementations for a, b, c, d and e - did you mean to use Interfaces?

Comment: basically I don't want to use abstract as I will be forced to implement all members of the base class, I need a way of implementing what I need in the derived classes

Comment: thanks @Mafii I think using interfaces would be one way of implementing it

Comment: If your interface contains `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and `e` members, any class implementing that interface will be forced to implement all five members too.

Comment: All properties/methods defined *must* be implemented by any actual object conforming to the definition.  Whether they are implemented by the objects Class or by one of its inherited classes is up to you, but it *must* be implemented *somewhere*.  There's **no such thing as an optional property or method** as that would violate any interface contract.

Comment: @RBarryYoung yes, this is true! However, it can be cirumvented by defining a Interface for every single need. Since you can only have one base class (you can have multiple interface implemented) I think thats where OP has his problems.

Comment: @JackM Aren't you just after virtual properties?

Comment: @Uno no - you cant choose what properties you implement with virtual properties: "The virtual keyword is used to modify a method, property, indexer, or event declaration and allow for it to be overridden in a derived class." They are already implemented by the base class, thats not what Jack wants

Comment: @JackM I'll add the answer.

Comment: @Mafii yes, but that's something entirely different, which seems to be unrelated to what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @RBarryYoung maybe I misunderstood him, idk. using virtual doesnt solve his problem Imo. Properties are still there, just implemented by the base class, and they allow to be overridden.

Comment: @Mafii Still, the OPs question is extremely vague and its very unclear what it is that they are looking for, so you may be right ...

Comment: @RBarryYoung seems like I misunderstood him then. Its not very clearly worded I agree

Comment: I may have been unclear as It is something I have done in the past but I couldn't find myself, sorry to anyone, but thanks I got what I needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood the question, you would like to optionally rewrite the implementation of the properties in the base class.

You can use the `virtual` keyword:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public virtual int a { get; set; }
    public virtual int b { get; set; }
    public virtual int c { get; set; }
    public virtual int d { get; set; }
    public virtual int e { get; set; }
}
```

in such a way you can optionally override it in the derived classes:

```
public class DerivedClass: BaseClass
{
    public override int a { get; set; }
    public int derivedClass1 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use `virtual` keyword

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public virtual int a { get; set; }
    public virtual int b { get; set; }
    public virtual int c { get; set; }
    public virtual int d { get; set; }
    public virtual int e { get; set; }
}
```

that way derived classes will override needed properties while leaving untouched the base class other ones

Comment: You are welcome. And I'd be happy to hear from the brave downvoter how to further enhance my answer, too

Comment: @user3598756 I didn't downvote you, but it could be that he thougth that your answer was totally wrong due to the question being poorly worded.

Comment: @JackM, what was it? Not the solution anymore?

Comment: sorry I can only mark one as the answer and I have two similar solutions

Comment: so what was the criterium? Since they are identical I'd go for timing. Just for knowledge but leave things as they are